# Why do we multiply with a (-1) on LHS if it's negative while solving inequalities

Tags: inequality

While solving
(-10)/(x-1) > 0

We first multiply by -1 on both sides change inequality and then proceed to solve.
If that's not done I get a wrong ans.
Why's that?

Comment: Show us how you got a wrong answer without multiplying by $-1.$ Seems like you can solve without, you just have to be careful.

Comment: To show your work more clearly, this is recommended: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: Multiplying by $-1$ is **not**  necessary to solve this inequality, it's just something that's often done because it's more convenient to have the variable term be positive. If you edit your question and show us your steps, perhaps we can show you where you went wrong.

Comment: @A.J. I just uploaded a new question and included the image in that. Pls check it

Comment: You're just making a small mistake with the inequality on the right. You have $\frac{-10}{x-1} > 0$; in order for that to be true, $x-1$ needs to be **negative**, so $x < 1$, the same as what you got when you multiplied by $-1$. If you're relying on the graphs to determine the solution, then don't forget that changing the function also changes the graph; while your graph on the left side is correct, the graph on the right side needs to be reflected in the line $x=1$, so that the positive portion is now to the left of $1$ and the negative section is to the right of $1$.

Comment: @A.J. Okk! Finally understood it thanks

Answer (score 1):

If$$3\gt2$$then multiplying by negative reverses the sign of inequality$$-3\lt-2$$

Comment: I know thatI'm asking why we do that in the question I wrote

Answer (score 1):

The multiplication by $-1$ is to help in isolating for $x$; this is fairly self-evident. Compare it to the example of trying to solve for $x$ in

$$-2x < 0 \qquad - \frac{1}{x} > 0 \qquad -5(x+1) = 0$$

We need to get rid of the negative somehow; multiplying (or dividing) by $-1$ helps achieve that.

---

As for why it flips the inequality, think on a simpler level.

Obviously, these inequalities hold:

- $2<3$
- $-1 < 5$
- $-3 < -1$

If we multiply each number involved by $-1$, we get these inequalities:

- $-2 \; \square \; -3$
- $1 \; \square \; -5$
- $3 \; \square \; 1$

What inequality signs should go where the boxes are? Then you see why you have to flip the sign: it essentially is because multiplying by $-1$ reverses the order of the numbers, as if flipping them through a mirror.